# Why does command prompt show numbers before I begin?

Tags: c, file-io, printf, scanf

The command prompt shows numbers before program begins. Why? `2687688` is given
but the numbers won't write to file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE*nfPtr;
    int n;
    if ((nfPtr=fopen("c:\\Users\\raphaeljones\\Desktop\\newfile.dat","w"))==NULL)
{
    printf ("Sorry! The file cannot be opened\n");
}
    else
{//else 1 begin

    printf("Enter numbers to be stored in file\n");
    printf("%d",&n);
    while (!feof(stdin)){
          fprintf(nfPtr,"%d",n);
          scanf("%d",&n);
          }
}//else 1 ends
        fclose(nfPtr);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you have `printf("%d",&n);` - doesn't your compiler emit warnings ?

Comment: Also, move `fclose(nfPtr)` in the body of the `else` block. Because `fclose(NULL)` is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute

```
printf("%d",&n);
```

with

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

> `printf` Writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout)
>
> `scanf` Reads data from stdin

In your code you are printing n, that is not initialized, that a random number is printed out after `"Enter numbers to be stored in file"` string.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from other issues, in your code

```
 printf("%d",&n);
```

is absolutely wrong and invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
. Maybe you meant

```
 scanf("%d",&n);
```

to *scan-in* the number.

That said, please see, [why you should refrain from using `!feof(file)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)